# VS Code not auto indenting in jupyter notebook / ipynb files

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, auto-indent

I must have accidentally disabled auto indent in VS code jupyter notebook. Does anyone know how to fix this? For example, indentation on the next line after creating a function.

Comment: This has happened to me as well. I reinstalled every extension, conda and I checked settings and everything seems "fine"....